# How to solve import cv2 import error on Amazon linux?

Tags: python, opencv, amazon-ami

I am using an Amazon linux machine with python 2.7.
I am working with Anaconda. 
When typing:

```
import cv2
```

I get the following exception:

```
ImportError: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried to search online but did not find a solution for amazon linux.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed instructions in this page and worked fine:
https://ubunifu.co/python/installing-libgtk-x11-2-0-so-0-in-amazon-linux-ami-2017-03-1

```
$ sudo yum install ftp://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/hicolor-icon-theme-0.11-1.1.el6.noarch.rpm
$ sudo yum install ftp://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/atk-1.30.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
$ sudo yum install ftp://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/gdk-pixbuf2-2.24.1-6.el6_7.x86_64.rpm
$ sudo yum install ftp://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/gtk2-2.24.23-9.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

As it seems Amazon AMI doesn’t have a yum repository for the libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0. So, we can install it from CentOs distro packages.